# OS X Automator: Using custom command in AppleScript's "do shell script"

Tags: applescript, automator, bash

I have recently asked a question about automatically inserting a value produced by a custom executable into a prompt field. Please look over [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311655/os-x-automator-automatically-insert-text-into-appearing-text-prompt) to know exactly what I am talking about.

The reply I got was exactly what I was looking for except for one but crucial detail.

To make things short: I am looking for a way to make `do shell script` to accept custom executables. Running my custom command `vpnpw` in terminal works perfectly fine. However, AppleScript's `do shell script` says it's unknown.

Does anyone know how to make these custom executables available globally?

Answer (score 1):

What's the fully qualified pathname of the executable?  If it's not within in the `$PATH` that's passed to the `do shell script` command, which is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`, then you'll need to use the fully qualified pathname of the executable.

To make an executable available globally, it must be in a directory that's included in the `$PATH`.

You can also add an *alias* or *symbolic link* to the target executable to a directory that's in the $PATH if you do not want to either append the path to it in the `$PATH` however keep in mind if the executable is dependent on files that are within its directory then adding the directory path to the `$PATH` is what you'll need to do.